# Enlarge find all references font size in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, find-all-references

So MS added the new style for "find all references", but now I cannot find how to change the font size of the "Code" column! I want it bigger, but when I change the Environment font it only affects the other columns (File, Project, etc.). Is there any way to increase the font size of the "Code" column?

If not - is there any (preferably free) extension available for VS2017 that will replace the new default find all references window?
[image: Find all references too small]

Comment: Not find the way to change the font and color for it, maybe you could use certain extension tool like the ReSharper to help you analyze project references: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Finding_Usages__Optimizing_References.html

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT ReSharper is too expensive, I'm looking for other alternative

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found the solution!

`Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Show settings for`

then choose `Editor Tooltip` and select the desired font and size.

This affects the tooltips as well as the find all references window!

[image: Font is bigger now]

Comment: In case anyone is also looking to also adjust the **background** color for the _Find All References_ window, there is now a semi-workaround by using `Tools - Options - Environment - Find And Replace - 'Use editor background in the Find All References tool window'` as explained [in this VS feedback item](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/29851/no-way-to-change-find-all-references-background-co.htm)

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, the option is under "Tools -> Options -> **Environment ->** Fonts and Colors -> Show settings for:".

Comment: Unlike other font settings, the change isn't applied immediately, only at the next reference search (VS2022)